# Is there a general proof of convergence of variational quantum eigensolvers (VQEs) to the minimum eigenvalue?

Tags: vqe, optimization

For QAOA  it is known that in the large $p$ limit, the algorithm finds the minimum/maximum (see article [A Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4028v1)).

Is there  in general a proof for VQE starting from, let's say, uniform superposition state? Is there  a standard construction of a  circuit (ansatz preparation? not sure about the terminology) that the algorithm converges in some limit?

Comment: I guess that depending on the problem. For certain chemistry problems, it is possible to guarantee convergence if you use says the UCCSD ansaz. I also feel like the classical optimizer plays a huge role whether you can reach convergence or not as well...

Comment: I have seen that as well in the literature. A related question is whether QAOA works non-combinatorial optimizations over binary variables or only combinatorial ones? I mean that the cost function is $C(z) = \sum_\alpha \beta_\alpha C_\alpha(z)$ where $\beta_\alpha$ may be real values, and $C_\alpha$ are  clauses.